# How to make elements in grid to have their own specific height?

Tags: html, css, grid

[image]

This is the following Container. 
You have noticed that last element in the grid (**Table like Structure**) looks weird. YES, it looks weird because it is taking the maximum height of the element present in that row. 
I just want the element to be look like...
[image]

Can you help me what CSS property should be used inside bodyContainer where I applied **grid**. 
This is the CSS I have applied.

```
.bodyContainer{
    margin-top: 3rem;
    padding: 0rem 2rem 0rem 2rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Put the contents of the fourth column inside a wrapper `<div>` so that the border is around the desired contents and not the whole column

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the `align-items: start;` style. That will tell each child to be its own natural height. The default is `align-items: stretch;`